# Why "Could not locate the assembly "System.IdentityModel.Services" on Ubuntu agent but not windows agent?

Tags: msbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task, msbuild-task

Long story short, I was able to build a bitbucket .NET/MVC/Angular project successfully on windows 2019 azure hosted agent, as well as ubuntu agent. The reason I want to build it on ubuntu is because I noticed the build time is way faster than that of the windows agent, which makes sense considering the platforms.

I am facing this warning on Ubuntu 20 azure hosted agent:

```
warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.IdentityModel.Services". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
```

I dont get this warning on the windows 2019 agent, and i see there is a reference already included in the `.csproj` file:

```
<Reference Include="System.IdentityModel.Services" />
```

and the following packages in `packages.config` file

```
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net471" />
```

While the build is working just fine, Im curious to resolve this warning on Ubuntu agent, since its not showing up on windows 2019 agent.

screenshot of my build pipeline so far:

[image: build tasks]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.services?view=netframework-4.8 WIF and its namespaces are .NET Framework only. In other words, Windows only.

Comment: @LexLi oh man, theres no other way around it? I was just happy to have made the build finally work on ubuntu after a month of trying :(

Comment: You might try to use the referenced assemblies NuGet package, https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/tree/master/releases/reference-assemblies but still Windows is a better option.

Comment: @LexLi the problem is windows build takes like 7 minutes to finish, it's too long especially when I have to debug the build. Ubuntu takes 3 mins by comparison, that's why I wanna use ubuntu

Comment: @LexLi Figured it out!!! :)
Check answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to this post [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/1300418/view.html):

Add this script/lines to the `.csproj` file:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net471.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net471.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net471.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net471.targets')" />
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net471.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net471.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net471.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net471.targets'))" />
</Target>
```

In addition you also need to add such content into the packages.config file:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net471" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" />
```

and with that, it now runs on Ubuntu beautifully!!!
Just check out these duration differences,

- 2.5 mins on Ubuntu 20
- 8.5 mins on Windows 2019

insane!

[image: durations]

Comment: Just some comments: 1) Usually people don't care much about how long it takes for CI/CD pipeline. I wonder what takes that long on Windows, and you might use  MSBuild bin log to dig further, https://msbuildlog.com/ 2) Even though you can build on Ubuntu with the referenced assemblies package, I don't think any unit test cases can be executed there. That's not a valid CI/CD setup yet.

Comment: @LexLi those are good points, the 1st point, the faster the build time is, the faster I'm able to debug the build pipeline as I build one for the 1st time. As I have finished the build pieces now, the next task to add is publishing the AngularOutput artifacts to Azure web service. If I run into issues and it's running on windows, I'll have to wait 8 mins everytime I gotta debug/trial and error different scenarios compared to just 2 mins. Regarding 2nd point, that may be true, but the project developer told me we dont need to build the test files, as I dont think they have any tests.

Answer (score 1):

We could check the installed software for each hosted agent, we can see that the [Windows 2019 agent](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#net-framework) has installed .NET Framework 4.7.2 4.8 and it is not installed on the [Ubuntu 20 azure hosted agent](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-README.md).

The MSB3245 error is typical warning/error when the referenced assembly can't be found or can't be loaded. `System.IdentityModel.Services` is an assembly in .NET Framework. According to the [doc](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework): .NET Framework is a **Windows-only version** of .NET for building any type of app that runs on **Windows**.

[image]

**Update1**

We could see that the [Ubuntu 20 hosted agent](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-README.md#net-core-sdk) has installed `.NET Core SDK`, If you want use Ubuntu hosted agent, you could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/) to port from `.NET Framework` to `.NET Core`, then we could run the code on the `Ubuntu hosted agent`

Note: The road will be long and difficult, we still recommend that you use Window hosted agent

Comment: I see, so theres no way to make this work on ubuntu? I spent so much time fixing another issue with VBCSCompiler on ubuntu agent to make the build finally succeed, it would be discouraging if this warning about identity services cannot be resolved after all the trouble I went through to use ubuntu for the faster build time :(

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer, you could check the update1, I recommend that you use Window hosted agent instead of Ubuntu hosted agent.

Comment: Hi Vito, Ive tried some workarounds from here like Adding `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies" Version="1.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />` to the csproj file but that didnt help. Also, I cant upgrade the project to .NET core myself since I didnt really create it, Im just tasked with building the CI pipeline, thats it.

Comment: You could also try to [install self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) and then run it on the self-hosted agent. And Windows agent is still a better option.

Comment: Ya I prefer windows too, but it's just too slow...it takes currently 7 mins for the build to finish. On ubuntu it's taking 2 mins by comparison. Thats a HUGE difference